# find strings that are alnum and can contain _ or #

Tags: string, filter, sed, grep

I've tried several times to get grep or sed to do what I want it to and have so far failed so if anyone can help I would be very grateful!

I have a text file which is populated with lines of strings I've pulled from a memory dump using sysinternals strings.exe.
I now need to filter this file down to individual strings as a lot of it is useless garbage (e.g: &644*/;@) or several strings attached on one line e.g:

```
&644*/;@
string1
string2;@%string3*£""^string4
```

The strings I need can consist of alphanumeric, underscores (_) and hashes (#) so string_string#1 or examplestring or example_string.

In summary, using the above example I need to be able to filter string1, string2, string3 and string4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want, but perhaps you are just looking for:

```
 < path-to-text-file tr \; '\012' | tr -d -c 'A-Za-z0-9_#'
```

This will remove all of the characters you do not want and convert semi-colons to newlines.

Or perhaps you just want

```
< path-to-text-file tr -sc 'a-zA-Z0-9_#' '\012'
```

which will convert every sequence of contiguous characters that you want to ignore with a single newline.

Comment: Thanks! the second one does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed:

```
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]_#]\+/\n/g' dump > strings
```

Or inline, if your sed supports it:

```
sed -i 's/[^[:alnum:]_#]\+/\n/g' dump
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to exclude "644" (which is an alphanumeric string), I'd suggest

```
grep -o '[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_#]*'
```